# Google Sheets - Passing Information from Different Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

In Google Sheets, each day of the month I keep track of the total amount of time I spend playing games, the average time spent playing games, the average number of people I play games with, and the average number of people in the game lounge. To keep a log of this, I create a new tab/sheet for each day with each sheet being named using the format "mm.dd.yyyy". There's other information on each daily sheet as well.

I've made another tab/sheet that shows a monthly overview that displays the date (with the mm.dd.yyyy format), the day of the week, the total amount of time I spend playing games, the average time spent playing games, the average number of people I play games with, and the average number of people in the game lounge for each day.

The format of this sheet can be seen here:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to get that information from each daily sheet and put it into the monthly Overview sheet. I know that I can get information from a certain sheet by doing "='03.01.2020'!N65", where I've called the name of the sheet and the cell location. But, it's very tedious having to do that for each day of the month and for each bit of information.

Is there a way I could easily and efficiently update the the monthly Overview? Or could I create a method in the Script Editor that would take in two parameters - the date from the Day column (which would refer to the sheet I need to access) and the cell that has the info I need such as the Total Time spent playing games.

If there is a way to do this, let me know because I've been trying to figure this out for awhile.

Comment: Welcome. Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet, and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: So every sheet you have in your spreadsheet is a month? Could you maybe share a sample sheet? 

You could maybe take a look at [`QUERY` ](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).